# Assistance with knockout validation

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Using the Knockout library, I wrote a ViewModel (largely based on their online guidance), that does a bit of validation.  Everything works perfect except...

1) Validation invokes immediately once my dialog is launched

2) I'd like to bind the validation to the dialog button instead of the input box, and have it trigger only when users click the "Add New Account" button.

A link to my JSFiddle is below.  Thanks for any guidance you can provide.

http://jsfiddle.net/9PV7X/

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="createAccount">Create New Account</a> 

<div id="newAccount" title="New Account">
<p> 
    <span class="ui-state-highlight" data-bind='visible: accountName.hasError, text: accountName.validationMessage'> </span>
</p>
  <form>
  <fieldset>
      <label for="name">Enter Account Name:</label><br />
    <input type="text" id="accountName" data-bind='value: accountName, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"'  />
  </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

**ViewModel**

```
$("#newAccount").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 450,
    height: 300,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Add New Account": function () {
            // post data
            $(this).dialog("close"); 
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$("#createAccount")
    .click(function () {
        $("#newAccount").dialog("open");
    });

    ko.extenders.required = function(target, overrideMessage) {
    target.hasError = ko.observable();
    target.validationMessage = ko.observable();

    function validate(newValue) {
       target.hasError(newValue ? false : true);
       target.validationMessage(newValue ? "" : overrideMessage || "This field is required");
    }

    validate(target());
    target.subscribe(validate); 
    return target;
};

function ViewModel(account) {
    this.accountName = ko.observable(account).extend({ required: "An account name is required" });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Cheers,

Claude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do two modification on your code:

1. To prevent Validation to be invoked immediately once the dialog is launched just remove or comment this line `validate(target());` . This is just an initial validation.
2. Apply model binding when you open your dialog, you don't need to apply it if the dialog is not open:

like this

```
open:function(){
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
}
```

kindly check this **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/9PV7X/7/)**

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The error message is suppressed when the dialog first loads, but validation does not fire when clicking the Add New Account button.. thoughts?

Comment: @mynameisneo i updated my jsfiddle to fire validation on click the Add New Account button.

Comment: @mynameisneo you welcome, i edited my jsfiddle again. please check it